# iOS: Adding array to create a dynamic cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to create a table cell which is populated with text fields. However the number of text fields is never a fixed amount. I figured I'd just shoot the array into the table cell and then do the rest from there.

Yet I can't seem to figure out how to do this... Ideally I would be able to access an array with the necessary data from `- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier` in my `UITableViewCell`. Then loop through and allocate the necessary number of text fields necessary.

I added a `myArray` property to the cell, then did an `alloc init` in the method above, but still can't access it from my view controller. e.g. `cell.myArray = ...`

How can I accomplish this? Is there a better way I should be doing it? This is just the first way that came to mind. Any help is appreciated, thanks guys.

EDIT (Rough Example):

```
//MyCell.h

@interface ITDContactDetailsCell : UITableViewCell
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *myArray;
@end


//MyCell.m

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
        self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
        if (self) {
            _myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            //Do some stuff with array (like add UITextViews)
        }
}

//MyViewController.m

- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)table cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  NSString *cellIdentifier = @"ContactDetails4LineCell";
  MyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
     //This doesn't even register
     cell.myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"a", @"b", nil];

}
```

Comment: Can you show where do you assign that array and where do you access that array after assign?

Comment: I just wrote up a rough a example. All imports are correct, and I can access other things in the cell (like UIViews). Then again I do an addSubview for those, I don't if there's a similar version for arrays or something.

Comment: I think you are on the right track.  But you do understand that an array is just an in-memory structure, not a UI element?  It's up to your custom cell to do something with that array so the user can see it, e.g. to create a UILabel for each string in the array and add those labels as subviews.

Comment: Yes I understand that (I have working table cells using several cell identifiers, I just figured it would be simpler/cleaner to do it in an array). I just can't even access the array from my UIViewController to populate it with anything.

Comment: Turns out Xcode was just glitching. Restarted it and I can now access my array. Thanks for your help man. Going to delete this question in like 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may build your own setter on the `ITDContactDetailsCell` class.  The following signature is what gets called when the VC says `cell.myArray = ...`

```
- (void)setMyArray:(NSMutableArray *)array {

    _myArray = array;  // this + what ARC does to it is what the synthesized setter does

    // here, we do something with the array so the user can interact with it
    // labels are simpler, but textFields are the same idea
    CGFloat x = 10, y = 10;
    for (NSString *string in array) {
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(x,y,60,20);
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        label.text = string;
        [self addSubview:label];
        x += 60;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change flow. Because

- It's called first.`- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style
  reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier` and does nothing due to `empty array`.
- cell.myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"a", @"b", nil];
  this will execute second after first point, so this also does
  nothing.

**Update:**

Try this..

in cell.h

```
-(void)addTextField;
```

in cell.m

```
-(void)addTextField
{
   // Do your stuff
}
```

in Your viewcontroller

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)table cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  NSString *cellIdentifier = @"ContactDetails4LineCell";
  MyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
     //This doesn't even register
     cell.myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"a", @"b", nil];
     [cell addTextField];

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it turns out it was just an Xcode glitch. Restarted and I can now access cell.myArray (the example was just rough).